# What are the patterns on this monitor's screen?

Tags: display, visual-artifacts

I've stumbled upon this picture while looking for reviews comparing Dell U2717D (left) and ViewSonic VP2768 (right) monitors. I wonder what are the patterns on the Dell's screen here? Is it some kind of flickering?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pattern is called [moiré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern).

It's an effect that occurs when two patterns overlap at an angle and happens mostly when you take an image with a digital camera and the pattern being photographed doesn't line up with the camera's sensor's pixels.

Comment: Note that the effect has a relation to "low frequency sampling" - and directly related to the anti aliasing filter in digital cameras with lower megapixel counts. There is some point in megapixel counts where the effect diminishes, and "only" appears in special cases. These cases are common with the text on the linked wikipedia page.